# Where should caching logic lie, the View Model or model

Tags: mvvm

Lets say I have some UI with a combo box and depending on the combobox selection a listbox gets filled up with items. Each time the index changes you need to fetch data from a remote endpoint and the data does not change so there is a definite advantage to caching the listbox items per combobox index.
Where is the correct place to cache this. In the ViewModel when the index changes I do something like call out to the model to get me all the items for the index value.
Should I cache in the view model and not call out to the model, or should I always call out to the model and let the model decided a caching strategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [In which layer implement the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340173/in-which-layer-implement-the-cache) they show several diffrent ways to impliment caching

basicly you should either have a decorator on the data access layer or crosscutting cache manager.